# Easier way to spell out Month and Day based on a numeric cell input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the header for one of my spreadsheets I have to type "For the X Months Ended MMMMMM DD, YYYY" where X is the number of the month spelled out in English (I.E. 'Twelve').

The date in question is always the last day of the period.  The period is defined in a cell in numeric form (for use in formulae).  For example, October is period 1.  So what I did to automate this was the following monstrous formula using the workbook name and 3 named ranges as 'helpers':

```
="For the " & INDEX(MonthNumbers,MATCH(INDEX(PeriodMonths,'Franchise Fees'!U2,),CalendarMonths,0)) & " Months Ended " & TEXT(DATE(MID(CELL("Filename",A1),SEARCH("_",CELL("Filename",A1))-4,4),MOD('Franchise Fees'!U2+10,12),1)-1,"MMMMMMMMM DD, YYYY")
```

MonthNumbers is just a list of the numbers 1-12 in English (One, Two,...)

PeriodMonths is the list of month names offset by 10 months (so that 1 = October)

CalendarMonths is the list of month names in normal order (so that 1 = January)

Now, I'm proud of this formula, but once my boss sees it she is going to flip out (she hates long formulae).  So I need to ask:

Is there a simpler way to do this?  It feels like there should be.  Also, I CANNOT use VBA.  This is a macro-free workbook.

Comment: Why not just hide the formula? That way, she can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [custom format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx) and just have to type in the date. Right-click the cell, choose Format Cells... and fill in this Custom Format:

```
"For the month ended" mmmm dd, yyyy
```

[image]

You could of course use a shorter version of your formula to figure the date.

Comment: Woops, just saw the "12 months" part.

Comment: Thanks for the try.  Yeah, I immediately jumped to formatting first thing before realizing it couldn't do what I needed.  The trick is that I only want to update the one numeric cell and avoid typing the date every time.  Because I've forgotten before, and if you can make something automatic, why not?

Answer (score 0):

I rather agree with your boss. A 247 character formula does not seem particularly well-suited for the results required.

I would suggest something like two versions of the same (18 character) formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,T,2,0)
```

and the same again with `2` replaced by `3` (where A1 is the entered month number).

Keep the lookup table (named `T` by me - not best practice, but short!) and extend it to include the month-end dates (calculated, if you wish) properly aligned (so October is in the same row (or column  if you prefer HLOOKUP instead of VLOOKUP) as `1` and `one`.

The stumbling block however might be that I would use four cells for the output, the first with `For the` the third with `Months Ended` (these don't change, so why include them in a formula?), the other two with the LOOKUP formulae and suitable formatting.

If you must have all this in a single cell (and don't mind the oddity of "one Months") then the following might be preferred:

```
="For the "&VLOOKUP(A1,T,2,0)&" Months Ended " &TEXT(VLOOKUP(A1,T,3,0),"mmmm dd, yyy")
```

that is also regrettably long, but at least is considerably less long.

Comment: Hmm....I was hoping I was just missing something with Date formats or something that might substitute for my Match/Indexes.  Your solution certainly makes the formula less lengthy, but it just transfers that length into helper cells that store the data in its stead.  If the boss thinks that looks less menacing then I'll use it.  Thanks.